# How to solve Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions exception

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-functions-runtime

When migration Azure function v3 to version v4, using this [guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=azure-cli%2Cin-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#breaking-changes-between-3x-and-4x) the Azure function is failing to start due to a file not found error. I have followed the Migration guideline and still not succeeding, how would I solve this?

Copy of Exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*****'. The system cannot find the file specified. at ***.***.Startup.Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
```

I am also getting a
`Runtime version: Error`

Answer (score 0):

I tried upgrading by creating a net core 3.1 function and adding dependency injection like explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

I have that using: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
But I see you use "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions".

It upgraded right after I changed the target:

[image]

did you try to run the nuget under the VS console?

Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions -Version 6.0.0
or try
[image]

the last resource would be creating a new project V4 using isolated mode and move classes across or a v4 using this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection and move files accross

Comment: I have updated in the csproj file and still no luck, tried restarting the Azure function multiple times as well. Also tried updating the package and still getting this error.